# Controlling pointtype in gnuplot 5.0 with strings

Tags: gnuplot

In gnuplot 4.6 the following piece of code worked:

```
tip="3 4"
plot for [i=1:2] sin(x*i) w point pointtype word(tip,i)+0
```

Each curve was plotted with the corresponding point symbol: the third symbol and the fourth symbol. Notice that '+0' converted the word into a number.

The same piece of code fails in gnuplot 5.0. It displays the curves either with a literal '1' (in the first iteration) and a '2' (in the second).

Why? Can pointtypes be controlled in gnuplot 5.0 in this way?

Answer (score 0):

In gnuplot 5 parsing of the argument provided for `pointtype` has changed, because now you can plot character point symbols (see third example at http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/lines_arrows.html). I guess that introduces the bug you are seeing.

Use `int(word(tip, i))` to get your example working:

```
tip="3 4"
plot for [i=1:2] sin(x*i) w point pointtype int(word(tip,i))
```

Comment: It worked, thanks.  I remember having spent some time in learning how to convert the string into a number so that pt word(string,i) would work. The "+0" got the stuff work in 4.6. Now int(word()) looks cute.